# Python C wrapper for function with argument CvCapture

Tags: python-2.7, ctypes, opencv3.0

I'm trying to run [YOLO v2](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) for detection. It works perfectly when I run examples at the website. Because I will add something depending on results, source code is a little bit hard for me that's why I want to use python wrapper. Original code contains python wrapper (darknet/python/darknet.py). but  it only works with images and I need real-time detection. I've checked wrappers on the net but I couldn't find video support. Also, I tried sending video frame-by-frame but the result is wrong and it was too slow.

Here is my question: 
There is a function in the YOLO's source code (image.c) **fget_image_from_stream(CvCapture *cap)** and this function returns image structure which is very useful for me.  I couldn't find how to define CvCapture in the python code. For examle, `void func(int a, float b)` defined as

```
func = lib.func
func.argtypes = [c_int, c_float]
func.restype = c_void_p
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: See [Structures and Unions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions) in the [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) documentation.  The `.argtypes` would be `[ctypes.POINTER(CvCapture)]` once you define the structure.

Comment: I got name error, _CvCapture is not defined_ I think I need to declare CvCapture struct inside my python code and for this, I need its structure

Comment: I did say "once you define the structure". Did you read the docs link?